# XP Standby worked Windows 8 Sleep does not

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, sleep, hibernate, standby

In my daily routine I depended very much on Standby previously in XP. Now with Windows 8 I can enable hibernate and it seems to work - startup takes 30 seconds after a shutdown and 15 seconds after an inactivity sleep plus BIOS POST time.

But the equivalent of Standby does not seem to work on my machine - Hibernate is disabled at this point. With SysInternals I get the following:

> C:\Users\Administrator>psshutdown -d -t 0
>
> PsShutdown v2.52 - Shutdown, logoff and power manage local and remote systems
>   Copyright (C) 1999-2006 Mark Russinovich
>   Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> Error shutting down system: The request is not supported.

I'm guessing from this that Windows 8 handles my legacy BIOS differently than XP.
How would I debug this?

Comment: First of all, check that all your hardware has the drivers installed. Sleep and Hibernate do depend on the drivers functionality, and the system cannot use these states if drivers do not support it.

Comment: @marawuti - My guess the reason your getting this error is that PsShutdown has not been updated to support Windows 8.

Comment: @marawuti See question [No Hybrid Sleep in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/q/546693/80304) for ways to diagnose sleep/hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue on Microsoft Surface Pro Win 8.
Solution:

```
powercfg -h on
```

It switch on hibernate mode.